# What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following operator?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Let $(\lambda_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N^{*}}}$ be a sequence of real numbers converging to $0$ and let $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N^{*}}}$ be an orthonormal family in a Hilbert space $H$. Define $T:H \rightarrow H$ by $$T(u) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lambda_{k}\langle u,u_{k}\rangle u_{k}$$

What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following operator?. what shall I do to know them? could anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: $\lambda_n$ and $u_n$ perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that for $u_l$ You have $$T(u_l)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_k<u_l,u_k>u_k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_k\delta_{kl}u_k=\lambda_lu_l$$
and thus $\lambda_l$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $u_l$.

If $T(u)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_k<u,u_k>u_k=\lambda u$ for some $\lambda$ then $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_k<u,u_k>u_k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda<u,u_k>u_k$$
implies $$\lambda_l=\lambda$$ for some $l$ or $\lambda=0.$

Comment: it is not clear for me why u wrote the last 5 lines, what are you doing in them?